# How to set UIManager fixed row height of JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a Java swing application, I want to set to all `JTable` of my application a fixed RowHeight.
So I have insert this line of code:

```
UIManager.put("JTable.rowHeight", 25);
```

But this code not works.

Answer (score 4):

Try these codes

```
UIDefaults jDefaults = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();

//change nimbusL&F Selection Background color
jDefaults.put("Table.rowHeight", new Integer(25)); 

//update ui trees
for(Window window : Window.getWindows()){
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(window);
}
```

or

```
UIManager.put("Table.rowHeight", 25);
```

Comment: Sorry but I have try to use, your code, but not works.

Comment: This is working for "nimbus L&F", not for all look and feels.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to set to all JTable of my application a fixed RowHeight.

There is no UIManager property. You can't just make up properties and expect it to work.

Check out [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for an application that will list the actual properties that you might be able to modify for a given LAF.

If you want to set the row height you need to do it for every table:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
table.setRowHeight( 25 );
```